# MFC's MoveWindow (int X, int Y, int Width,int Height,FALSE) causing Flicker issue

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have problem with MFC's(VC++) MoveWindow() Method, My specs are:

- .net Runtime 3.5
- VS 2008
- Windows XP

I am displaying images through MoveWindow() method, it first displays image and then adjust it according to the parameter passed. During adjustment a minor (visible) flicker effect occurs. I am guessing this issue is due to MoveWindow method. Please suggest me whats wrong. Please let me know if you need any more info.

** code updated :07 Sep, 2011

```
void CTMLead::ResizeWndToRatio(float fHeight, float fWidth)
{
    CPoint  TopLeft;
    float   Width;
    float   Height;
    float   Ratio;
    int     Cx;
    int     Cy;
    CString tempFileName;
    tempFileName = m_strFilename;

    //  Should we use the current window dimensions?
    if((fHeight <= 0) || (fWidth <= 0))
    {
        fHeight = (float)m_iHeight;
        fWidth = (float)m_iWidth;
    }
    ASSERT((fHeight > 0) && (fWidth > 0));
    if((fHeight <= 0) || (fWidth <= 0)) return;

    //  Compute the aspect ratio of the current viewport
    Ratio = fHeight / fWidth;

    //  Find the center point of the maximum viewing area
    Cx = (m_rcMax.right / 2) + m_rcMax.left;
    Cy = (m_rcMax.bottom / 2) + m_rcMax.top;

    //  If we use the maximum width allowed, is the height still small
    //  enough to fit on the screen?
    if((m_rcMax.right * Ratio) < m_rcMax.bottom)
    {
        //  Use the full width allowed and adjust the height
        Width  = (float)m_rcMax.right;
        Height = Width * Ratio;
    }
    else
    {   
        //  Use the maximum height available and adjust the width
        Height = (float)m_rcMax.bottom;
        Width = Height / Ratio;
    }

    //  Calculate the new coordinates of the upper left corner
    TopLeft.x = Cx - (ROUND(Width) / 2);
    TopLeft.y = Cy - (ROUND(Height) / 2);

    //  Update the size and offset
    m_iLeft   = TopLeft.x;
    m_iTop    = TopLeft.y;
    m_iWidth  = ROUND(Width);
    m_iHeight = ROUND(Height);

    m_fImageWidth=m_iWidth; 
    m_fImageHeight=m_iHeight;
    SetDstRect(0.0f, 0.0f, m_fImageWidth, m_fImageHeight);

    MoveWindow  (m_iLeft, m_iTop, m_iWidth, m_iHeight, FALSE );
}
```

Thanks,

Ali

Answer (score 1):

Do you use MoveWindow multiple times or do you just want to resize once? Are you drawing the image yourself? If you are, you can use double buffering yourself to reduce flicker. Otherwise, try playing with WM_CLIPSIBLINGS and WM_CLIPCHILDREN, that helps too sometimes. If you are resizing multiple times or multiple windows and that is the problem, use BeginDeferWindowPos().

Comment: I use MoveWindow on a mouseClick. I am not drawing Image myself, I have .tiff and .png images. So, I think in double buffering will not work in my case. Could you please help by code how to play with WM_CLIPSIBLINGS and WM_CLIPCHILDREN? Thanks in advance .. -Ali

Comment: You are drawing the image onto something, you say 'I am displaying images through MoveWindow()' but that doesn't make any sense. You need to start with explaining how you are drawing or displaying an image.

Comment: thanks for replying .. I have posted my code above that contains MoveWindow Method. I am new to MFC and working on a existing Code, so I am not much familiar with the background. My debugging shows MoveWindow() method displays images (tiff/png). There is some flicking problem when images are switched. Please guide me whats wrong... Thanks you.

Comment: MoveWindow() can't display images. The drawing is probably done in OnPaint since no standard controls can display tiff out of the box. Quite frankly, you seem to lack even a basic grasp of the concepts used (like the difference between loading, decoding and drawing an image) but what you're trying to do requires at least an intermediate level of win32 knowledge. I suggest getting the Petzold book and reading the first 5 or so chapters, and then the chapters on DC's and paint operations. After that you can understand how your control works and you can ask the right questions to get an answer.